# Java String index out of bound

Tags: java, string

Sir here i am trying to check is there any number is exists or not . if there any digit exists then it will print the digit. But when i am trying to run this code i am facing error. please help me to fix the error.

My code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test1{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = input.nextInt();
    String arr[]= new String[a];
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        arr[i]=input.next();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        String sub[] = arr[i].split("");
        for(int j=0;j<sub.length;j++){
            char x = arr[i].charAt(j);
            if(Character.isDigit(x)){
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    }   
  }
}
```

I am getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at test1.main(test1.java:13)
Java Result: 1
```

Would you please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: I dont know much of java, but `arr[i]=input.next();` of yours is taking the next input when the loop reaches its end, which is not there. Hence the error. Though I'm not sure.

Comment: Is is possible splitting with `""` is giving an extra unwanted empty space character?

Comment: @peeskillet - That's exactly what is happening. There is an extra element in the array returned by the split method which is blank and thus `charAt()` throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when it encounters no character in that String.

Comment: @R.J. Yea I've ran into this problem before. I print out the array (after splitting with `""`) as a list and I got `[, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: another problem occurs . i am trying to give two values as input and in first value when i am using space it is not taking the next one .
Sample input
2 // i am declaring the array size
ar 4a // first input
after that when i am pressing enter it is not taking my 2nd input . how do i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `String.split`, convert your string into a character array:

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  System.out.print("Enter number of strings: ");
  int a = input.nextInt();

  String arr[] = new String[a];
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    System.out.print(String.format("Enter string #%d: ", i + 1));
    arr[i] = input.next();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    for (char c : arr[i].toCharArray()) {
      if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        System.out.println(c);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I put your `Scanner` in a try-with-resources construct, since you weren't closing it correctly.

Example usage:

```
Enter number of strings: 3
Enter string #1: abc
Enter string #2: 1abc
Enter string #3: a1b2c3
1
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.lenght()`:

```
String sub[] = new String[arr[i].lenght()];
            for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length();j++){
                char x = arr[i].charAt(j);
                if(Character.isDigit(x)){
                System.out.println(x);
            }
}
```

**Edit:** The array `sub[]` isn't even used, so it doesn't have to be declared at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 for(int j=0;j<sub.length;j++)
```

to

```
for(int j=0;j<sub.length-1;j++)
```

I tested it and it works as expected :)

Thats is because the `length` of `sub` is 5 when the input string have a length of 4. For example: input `hello` have a length of 5 and after do `split("")` it has a length of 6 because it is `""+"h"+"e"+"l"+"l"+"o"` in the array. So the String in `sub` is one index bigger than the String in the array :)

Comment: i am giving sample output

Answer (score 0):

If you use `String.split("")` directly to build an **String[]** array. The first one is empty.

Let's split string "`123`" for example, you will gain a String[] array as `[,1,2,3]`, rather than `[1,2,3]`.

```
 String[] text = "123".split("");
 //[, 1, 2, 3]
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text));
```

This extra empty is the cause of Exception : `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:`

You can skip the first empty string, and start the index from **1** instead of **0**.

Change the following code

from

```
   for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        String sub[] = arr[i].split("");
        for(int j=0;j<sub.length;j++){
            char x = arr[i].charAt(j);
            if(Character.isDigit(x)){
            System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

to

```
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        String sub[] = arr[i].split("");
        for(int j=1;j<sub.length;j++){
            char x = arr[i].charAt(j-1);
            if(Character.isDigit(x)){
            System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

and you will get the expected result, an example is run as follows:

```
2
12dec
34
1
2
3
4
```